# What fuzzy logic approach does a scikit-fuzzy or skfuzzy Python library use?

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic, skfuzzy

I want to know that what fuzzy logic approach does a scikit-fuzzy (mostly known as skfuzzy) Python Library use? Is it forward chaining or backward chaining? Also, does it use Mamdani Technique or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out from [skfuzzy's documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/api/skfuzzy.control.html#skfuzzy.control.ControlSystemSimulation) that it uses Mamdani Technique. And it depends on us, we can both forward and backward chaining methods using skfuzzy.

Forward chaining is data-driven, that means, first we give data, then rules and then it  predicts output, where as backward chaining is goal-driven, that means first we predict output, system used that output to see what possibilities (rules) could result in this prediction, and take the random rule for the shortlisted, and then take the output of that rule and show us that.